# Keep a specific number of objects in an AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering if there's a way by which I would be able to restrict number of objects in an S3 bucket. My usecase is I'm pushing a backup file everyday to S3 and want something wherein I'm able to keep only 10 latest files and the older ones get removed automatically.

Tried searching a lot over the web and AWS docs but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS offers lifecycle policy on S3 buckets where retention can be configured on object level. This solved my problem. Posting it for future reference of fellow SO users. More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no in-built functionality that will do this.

You could, however, implement it yourself:

- Create an Amazon S3 Event that triggers an AWS Lambda function when a new object is stored
- Code the Lambda function to count the number of objects, and delete the oldest objects if it is above a desired count

This would be relatively simple to accomplish.

Make sure it is only counting within a given folder, so it doesn't accidentally delete too many files!

Comment: I'm aware it can be done using Lambda but was expecting AWS's native support on this. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Amazon S3 is basically a "simple storage service" (S3). Think of it like the world's biggest disk drive. It has some clever capabilities (eg website hosting, lifecycle policies, access controls) but it can't have every feature that everybody wants. Fortunately, most requests can be handled with additional services like Lambda functions. Interestingly, I've never seen anyone else request the ability to limit the number of files.